# How to insert multiple checkbox values to database?

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, form-submit

I have the following piece of code inside a html form tag :

```
<label for="client">Services Included:</label>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="Spa"> Spa </p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="service[]" value="Massage"> Massage </p>
    <p></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

And in the php code I have this:

```
      if(!empty($_POST['service']))
  {
    foreach ($_POST['service'] as $selected) 
    {
      $query7 ="INSERT INTO reservation_includes_service VALUES (3,'".$selected."');";
      $queryexe7 = mysql_query($queryexe7);

    }
  }
```

Although I have tried everything, the query doesn't work... Any ideas?
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: `mysql_query($queryexe7)` wrong variable. You're just creating some type of loop and is confused as to which variable to use. It's kind of like "monkey in the middle", if I could say.

Comment: @AngePapa [`mysql_query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) is wrong either way, ever seen that big red box when you click the link? Its been there for about 4.5 years.

Comment: Here `$queryexe7 = mysql_query($query7);` enjoy and check for errors. If that didn't work, well........ you have errors. `mysql_error()`.

Comment: and Lord only knows what `<form>` looks like or if you even have form tags, and/or if using the proper "method".

Comment: @Fred-ii- thank you very much! At first I thought it was something wrong with the query , I didn't notice there was an error at the execution of the query. It worked!! :P :)

Comment: @AngePapa You're welcome, glad to have helped. I posted an answer below to which you can mark off as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in comments and posting as a community wiki:

> *"mysql_query($queryexe7) wrong variable. You're just creating some type of loop and is confused as to which variable to use. It's kind of like "monkey in the middle", if I could say."*.

This is what you needed to use:

```
$queryexe7 = mysql_query($query7);
```

You should look into using the `mysqli_` or PDO API. `mysql_` is deprecated and deleted from PHP 7.

Comment: I posted as a community wiki since I didn't want rep from this.